# Extracting paddy transplant dates (like SoS in TIMESAT)

Tags: google-earth-engine, timesat

I am trying to get transplant dates of paddy in Northern India using this [code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/b7326ffebefcd3719909650be399c319).

The idea is to find 15% of the maximum of an SG fitted curve of MODIS EVI, and find the Day of Year which corresponds to when the ascending limb had that fraction, like the Start of Season definition in TIMESAT while setting the method to seasonal amplitude.

The approach currently is to subtract this fraction from the images, and find which values lie closest to it by running quality mosaic, thus also retaining the Day of Year.

```
function percentCompEVI(collection,studyArea,percent) {
  var pc15 = amplitude.select('EVI').multiply(percent);
  var SoS = qmMin.select('EVI').add(pc15.select('EVI')).addBands(qmMin.select('DayOfYear'))
  print ('pc15 name test',pc15);
  print ('SoS value', SoS)
  // Compute distance of every pixel from the 10th percentile in that location
  var withDist = collection.map(function(image) {
    return image.addBands(image.select('EVI')
    .subtract(SoS.select('EVI')).abs().multiply(-1)
    .clip(FC).rename('quality'))
  })
  return withDist.qualityMosaic('quality').abs()
  //Retain the corresponding DayOfYear value
  return withDist.select('DayOfYear').abs()
}
var percent=0.15; //range: 0-1
var percentCompImage = percentCompEVI(data_,FC,percent);
```

The goal is to do what TIMESAT does. i.e., add the fraction of

```
[Value @ t+1  -  Value @ t] / [15% fraction - Value @ t]
```

to the image index that corresponds to the image at the time t.
I am assuming this approach would return Day of year values other than the distinct 8-day intervals; but I am finding it hard to apply on GEE.

Comment: Figured it out.